# django exception while using Filter (ImportError: No Module named ..)

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I try using in Django the "filter" Method:

```
dumpData.objects.filter(bid = True)
```

I get the following Exception:

> ImportError: No module named Trades

```
 File "XXX\CacheUtil.py", line 141, in loadItems print DumpData.objects.filter(bid = True)
  File "XXX\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 141, in filter
    return self.get_query_set().filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "X:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 550, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "X:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 568, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "X:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1194, in add_q
    can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
  File "X:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1069, in add_filter
    negate=negate, process_extras=process_extras)
  File "X:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1248, in setup_joins
    field, model, direct, m2m = opts.get_field_by_name(name)
  File "X:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 307, in get_field_by_name
    cache = self.init_name_map()
  File "X:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 337, in init_name_map
    for f, model in self.get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model():
  File "X:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 414, in get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model
    cache = self._fill_related_many_to_many_cache()
  File "X:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 428, in _fill_related_many_to_many_cache
    for klass in get_models():
  File "X:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 167, in get_models
    self._populate()
  File "X:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 61, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "X:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 76, in load_app
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
  File "X:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named Trades
```

Trade is my Django App wich is in the settings.py under

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (    
(...),
'Trades')
```

DumpData is defined as:

```
class DumpData(models.Model):
    orderId = models.BigIntegerField()
    typeId = models.BigIntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=20)
    bid = models.BooleanField()
    issued = models.DateField()
    dateDumped = models.DateTimeField()
```

If I try only

```
dumbData.objects.all()
```

all works fine so it's probably not a Server/DB problem. (Also I can save the Date without an exception).

Comment: What is `Trades`? Are you importing it anywhere?

Comment: Trades is the name of the Django App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved my Problem.
The reason because it didnt worked was in the Project Strukture, i had:

```
\src
    \PackageNr1
       Main.py  <-- File where Django was called.
    \PackageNr2  <-- Package for the Django Files
       \trades   <-- Django App
          models.py , 
          views ...usw 
       settings.py  <-- Django Settings File
       manage.py
```

Witch this Struckture i could call things like "save()" or "object.all()" and it worked fine. But for most call it didnt worked. So i moved my Django Package into the Main Pakcage and now it works. The new Struckture looks like this:

```
 \src
    \PackageNr1
        \trades    <-- The django app
            models.py
            views ....
        Main.py
        settings.py <--Django Files
        manage.py
```

And this works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found any documentation about it, but I would suggest to use lowercase names for apps.
Also, try :

```
dumpData.objects.filter(bid = True).all()
```

Comment: .all() didnt worked, same Problem/Exception. Thanks for the advice to apps name, i will rename it.

Comment: and if you try `dumpData.objects.all().filter(bid=True)` ?